# Where to ask questions about logic + logic programming?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about logic + logic programming?

I have questions pertaining to theory, not code.

Do I post in cstheory.stackexchange, math.stackexchange, or somewhere else?

Comment: Sure, try either cstheory.stackexchange, stackoverflow

Comment: Some example questions would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "research level" , ask here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

> TCS covers a wide variety of topics including algorithms, data
>   structures, computational complexity, parallel and distributed
>   computation, probabilistic computation, quantum computation, automata
>   theory, information theory, cryptography, program semantics and
>   verification, machine learning, computational biology, computational
>   economics, computational geometry, and computational number theory and
>   algebra.
>
> My question is not a research-level question in TCS, where can I ask
>   it?
>
> For questions other than research-level questions in TCS, you may want
>   to consider the following places to ask:
>
> ```
> General Computer Science — Computer Science - Stack Exchange
> ```

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

If not research level, I'd ask at the general computer science. https://cs.stackexchange.com/